# Send Command via Modbus RS485

Tags: java

I try to send a command to Smart Meter to receive total_deliver(kwh). I have USB <-> RS485 converter and using jSerialComm library. I use two different format (str.getByte(), and binary initialize into byte array) try to convert command into byte array, but none of them get a response from smart meter. Does anyone know what did I do wrong?  Thanks!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        SerialPort[] Device_ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for (int i = 0; i < Device_ports.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("["+i+"]"+Device_ports[i].getSystemPortName()+":"+Device_ports[i].getDescriptivePortName()+"-"+Device_ports[i].getPortDescription());
        }
        SerialPort mySerialPort = Device_ports[1];
        
        String cmd = "0F04049E0002103B"; 
        byte[] arr = {(byte) 00001111, 00000100, 00000100, (byte) 10011110, 00000000, 00000010, (byte) 00010000, (byte) 00111011};
        byte[] byte_arr = cmd.getBytes();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            //Send(OpenPort(mySerialPort), arr);
            Send(OpenPort(mySerialPort), byte_arr);
            Recv(mySerialPort);
        }
        mySerialPort.closePort();
    }
```

Send

```
public static void Send(SerialPort mySerialPort, byte[] arr) 
    {
        if (mySerialPort.isOpen())
        {
            System.out.println("Send ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
            }
            mySerialPort.writeBytes(arr, arr.length);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Send fail");
        }
    }
```

Receive

```
public static byte[] Recv(SerialPort mySerialPort)
    {
        byte[] readbuffer = new byte[25];
        int counter = 0;
        try
        {
            while (counter <= 5)
            {
                while (mySerialPort.bytesAvailable() == 0 && counter <= 5)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(20000);
                    System.out.println("Receive: none");
                    counter++;
                }
                mySerialPort.readBytes(readbuffer, readbuffer.length);
                System.out.println("Receive: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < readbuffer.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(readbuffer[i]+" ");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return readbuffer;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `String.getBytes()` does? Are the values in `byte_arr` the values you think the meter wants? Have you stepped through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Neither what looks like what you intend to be hex values, nor what you intend to be binary values are actually that. What you need is ```(byte)0b0000_1111```  etc. for your values

Comment: Thank you guys reply. I found my problem and fix it!